# Trying to create a Navigation Bar back button to a Tab Bar Controller view

Tags: iphone, ios, view, tabs

I have a tab bar controller.
From one of the views i want to goto another view via a button, which i have done.
Once on that page i want to go back using the navigation bar.
This is the problem.
How do i get it to go back to the tab bar controller page?
Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange your view controllers as follows:

```
Tab bar controller
    Navigation Controller
        View Controller 1 - button to go View Controller 2 using segue
        View Controller 2
```

So, `View Controller 2` will have a back button to go to its previous view controller.

Comment: Hi thanks for that.. I am new to all this.. Where about does this go? In the h or m file? And where? Thanks

Comment: This is not code. This is how you should configure your storyboard